# python: Combined masking in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, nan

In a numpy array I want to replace all `nan` and `inf` into a fixed number. Can I do that in one step to save computation time (arrays are really big)?

```
a = np.arange(10.0)
a[3] = np.nan
a[5] = np.inf
a[7] = -np.inf
# a: [  0.   1.   2.  nan   4.  inf   6. -inf   8.   9.]

a[np.isnan(a)] = -999
a[np.isinf(a)] = -999
# a: [  0.   1.   2.  -999.   4.  -999.   6. -999.   8.   9.]
```

The code above works fine. But I am looking for something like:

```
a[np.isnan(a) or np.isinf(a)] = -999
```

Which does not work and I can see why. Just thinking it might be better if every item of a is only checked once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems to work:

```
a[np.isnan(a) | np.isinf(a)] = 2
```

`np.isnan()` and `np.isinf()` in fact return two boolean numpy arrays.

boolean numpy arrays can be combined with bitwise operations such as & and |

Comment: Wonderful! Whats the difference between "or" and " | "? Maybe bitwise logic?
by the way, I just tested it: the combined version is rougly 10% quicker. Edit: Ok, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Numpy comes with its own vectorized version of or:

```
a[np.logical_or(np.isnan(a), np.isinf(a))] = -999
```

While the above version is clear understanable, there is a faster one, which is a bit weird:

```
a[np.isnan(a-a)] = -9999
```

The idea behind this is, that 'np.inf-np.inf = np.nan`

```
%timeit a[np.isnan(a-a)] = -999
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 11.7 µs per loop
%timeit a[np.isnan(a) | np.isinf(a)] = -999
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 51.4 µs per loop
%timeit a[np.logical_or(np.isnan(a), np.isinf(a))] = -999
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 51.4 µs per loop
```

Hence the `|` and `np.logical_or` version seem to be internally equivalent

Answer (score 3):

You could use `np.isfinite` which verifies that a number is not infinite nor a NaN:

```
a[~np.isfinite(a)] = -999
```

Comment: That looks nice, too! What does ~ do?

Comment: `~` is logical *not*.