# Fastest way to find non-finite values

Tags: python, numpy

This is inspired by: [python: Combined masking in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45614447/python-combined-masking-in-numpy/45615347).

The task is to create a Boolean array of all values that are not finite. For example:

```
>>> arr = np.array([0, 2, np.inf, -np.inf, np.nan])
>>> ~np.isfinite(arr)
array([False, False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

To me, it seems this would be the fastest way to find the non-finite values, but it seems that there is a faster way. Specifically `np.isnan(arr - arr)` should do the same:

```
>>> np.isnan(arr - arr)
array([False, False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Timing it we see that it is twice as fast!

```
arr = np.random.rand(100000)

%timeit ~np.isfinite(arr)
10000 loops, best of 3: 198 µs per loop

%timeit np.isnan(arr - arr)
10000 loops, best of 3: 85.8 µs per loop
```

So my question is twofold:

1. Why is the `np.isnan(arr - arr)` trick faster than the "obvious" `~np.isfinite(arr)` version? Is there input which it does not work for?
2. Is there an even faster way to find all non-finite values?

Comment: Interestingly, in my machine (Linux 64 bits, Python 3, NumPy 1.13.1) the "obvious" option takes ~77.3 µs and the `isnan` option 135 µs. If I increase the size of `arr` to 10000000 the difference is even bigger, 12.5ms vs 89.8ms.

Comment: This is on windows 64 bit, python 2.7 and numpy 1.11.3.

Comment: @JonasAdler Can you add the timing code so others can reproduce (or not) your results?

Comment: I'm using `%timeit` in IPython just as written in the question.

Comment: What do your `%timeit`s show on the original example containing non-finite values? I get... 1.23 µs ± 8.58 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each) and 5.22 µs ± 22.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Comment: What happens when you dump some inf's in the larger test array? I'm also getting contradicting results. I put `arr[arr > 0.9] = np.inf` after `arr = np.random.rand(100000)`

Comment: Checking now on Python 2, NumPy 1.11.0 (still Linux 64), I get about the same times (125µs option 1, 131µs option 1), but if I increase the size again to 10000000 then I get 31ms for option 1 and 91.3ms for option 2. Maybe give a try with a bigger array on your platform.

Comment: And given your second example using the random finites, I get: 64 µs ± 596 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each) and 120 µs ± 1.05 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

Comment: So - looks like `isfinite` wins all round... could well be coming down to OS/system architecture stuff... but from a purely logical point of view - a non-finite number just carries a flag that can be checked... subtracting an array from itself requires calculations, silently handled exceptions for operations on nans, and allocation of a new array, so it's doing a lot more work - I wouldn't expect it to be faster whatsoever...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's hard to answer because `np.isnan` and `np.isfinite` can use different C functions depending on the build. And depending on the performance (which may well depend on the compiler, the system and how NumPy itself is built) of these C functions the timings will be different.

---

The ufuncs for both refer to a built-in `npy_` func ([source (1.11.3)](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.11.3/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.h.src#L194-L197)):

```c
/**begin repeat1
 * #kind = isnan, isinf, isfinite, signbit, copysign, nextafter, spacing#
 * #func = npy_isnan, npy_isinf, npy_isfinite, npy_signbit, npy_copysign, nextafter, spacing#
 **/
```

And these functions are defined based on the presence of compile time constants ([source (1.11.3)](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.11.3/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_math.h#L158-L188)):

```c
/* use builtins to avoid function calls in tight loops
 * only available if npy_config.h is available (= numpys own build) */
#if HAVE___BUILTIN_ISNAN
    #define npy_isnan(x) __builtin_isnan(x)
#else
    #ifndef NPY_HAVE_DECL_ISNAN
        #define npy_isnan(x) ((x) != (x))
    #else
        #if defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER < 1900)
            #define npy_isnan(x) _isnan((x))
        #else
            #define npy_isnan(x) isnan(x)
        #endif
    #endif
#endif

/* only available if npy_config.h is available (= numpys own build) */
#if HAVE___BUILTIN_ISFINITE
    #define npy_isfinite(x) __builtin_isfinite(x)
#else
    #ifndef NPY_HAVE_DECL_ISFINITE
        #ifdef _MSC_VER
            #define npy_isfinite(x) _finite((x))
        #else
            #define npy_isfinite(x) !npy_isnan((x) + (-x))
        #endif
    #else
        #define npy_isfinite(x) isfinite((x))
    #endif
#endif
```

So it might just be that in your case the `np.isfinite` has to do (much) more work than `np.isnan`. But it's equally likely that on another computer or with another build `np.isfinite` is faster or both are equally fast.

So, there is probably not a hard rule what the "fastest way" is. That just depends on too many factors. Personally I would just go with the `np.isfinite` because it *can* be faster (and isn't too much slower even in your case) and it makes the intention much clearer.

---

Just in case you're really into optimizing the performance, you can always do the negating in-place. That might decrease the time and memory by avoiding one temporary array:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.rand(1000000)

def isnotfinite(arr):
    res = np.isfinite(arr)
    np.bitwise_not(res, out=res)  # in-place
    return res

np.testing.assert_array_equal(~np.isfinite(arr), isnotfinite(arr))
np.testing.assert_array_equal(~np.isfinite(arr), np.isnan(arr - arr))

%timeit ~np.isfinite(arr)
# 3.73 ms ± 4.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit isnotfinite(arr)
# 2.41 ms ± 29.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit np.isnan(arr - arr)
# 12.5 ms ± 772 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Note also that the `np.isnan` solution is *much* slower on my computer (Windows 10 64bit Python 3.5 NumPy 1.13.1 Anaconda build)

Answer (score 0):

Using numba accelerator in parallel no-python mode will be faster than [the `isnotfinite` function and `~np.isfinite` @MSeifert answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45757512/13394817), which are among the fastest methods. If we prepare an example data using:

```
def data_(m, n, f):
    arr = np.random.random_integers(0, 10, m).astype(np.float64)
    n_ = np.random.permutation(m)
    arr[n_[:n//2]] = np.inf
    arr[n_[n // 2:n]] = -np.inf
    arr[n_[n:n+f]] = np.nan
    return arr
```

So, `~np.isfinite` can be jitted using numba as:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def numba_(arr):
    res = np.empty(arr.shape[0], dtype=nb.boolean)
    for i in nb.prange(arr.shape[0]):
        res[i] = ~np.isfinite(arr[i])
    return res

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def numba_full(arr):
    res = np.full(arr.shape[0], True)
    for i in nb.prange(arr.shape[0]):
        res[i] = ~np.isfinite(arr[i])
    return res
```

Benchmark on Google Collaboratory CPU (horizontal axis is referring to `m` for `data_`):
[temporary link to colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MS_61NuT32e8AxJdZz0iIwi11emMRrM3?usp=sharing)

[image]