# Implement "Block tumbling logic" in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am using a `numpy` array to model iron ore falling through a bunker.

As ore is extracted from the bottom of the bunker and is added to the top, it leaves an empty space represented as a `nan`. I am looking to model the ore falling vertically into the spaces created.

[image]

A simplified version of the array is below. The bunker is actually modelled in 3D, with a fourth dimension containing information about various features of the ore, but the 2D array illustrates the concept.

I want each column to "collapse" into the `nan` values as shown and add new `nan`s at the top to represent empty space left behind. I realise that I could do this by splitting the array into columns, dropping the nan values and adding more nans to the top one column at a time, but given the size of the array to be traversed, I'm wondering if there is a way to vectorise this "vertical collapse" operation across the whole array?

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan

# The input array has some columns "hanging" above nans
arr_input = np.array(
    [[nan, nan,  7.],
     [ 1.,  2., nan],
     [ 4.,  5., nan],
     [ 7., nan,  9.]]
)

# Drop each column into the nans and add nans at the top to keep the shape the same
arr_expected = np.array(
    [[nan, nan,  nan],
     [ 1., nan,  nan],
     [ 4.,  2.,  7.],
     [ 7.,  5.,  9.]]
)
```

**Edit** I came up with the following, although it is not vectorised.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan

arr_input = np.array(
    [[nan, nan,  7.],
     [ 1.,  2., nan],
     [ 4.,  5., nan],
     [ 7., nan,  9.]]
)
arr_expected = np.array(
    [[nan, nan,  nan],
     [ 1., nan,  nan],
     [ 4.,  2.,  7.],
     [ 7.,  5.,  9.]]
)

# Split out the array into columns using np.split (for loop line)
# Remove the non-nans from the column, then pad the top to fill
# Stack the result along axis 1 to get the original shape back
arr_output = np.stack([
    np.pad(
        col[~np.isnan(col)], 
        (np.isnan(col).sum(), 0), # Pad at top
        'constant', 
        constant_values=np.nan
    )
    for col in np.split(arr_input, arr_input.shape[1], axis=1)
], axis=1)

np.testing.assert_almost_equal(arr_output, arr_expected)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to sort the array column by column, but instead of on value, we sort on boolean `np.isnan(arr)` so the `nan` "floats" to top, similar to the idea of bubble sort. You probably want to investigate more on the `kind` argument of [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to make sure the original order are always preserved since we have duplicates in the boolean array. I think the default `quicksort` is not stable.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan

arr = np.array(
    [[nan, nan,  7.],
     [ 1.,  2., nan],
     [ 4.,  5., nan],
     [ 7., nan,  9.]]
)


# the sorted are the ordered row index with nan on top
# the column index are just created to fit numpy's indexing rules
arr[np.argsort(~np.isnan(arr), axis=0, kind='mergesort'), 
    np.repeat(np.arange(arr.shape[1]).reshape(1,-1), arr.shape[0], axis = 0)]
```

output:

```
array([[nan, nan, nan],
       [ 1., nan, nan],
       [ 4.,  2.,  7.],
       [ 7.,  5.,  9.]])
```

On my first (unsuccessful) try of the problem, I found a solution to simulate it "step by step" (fall one block at a time):

```
arr_empty = np.isnan(arr)
idx_move = (~arr_empty[:-1, :]) & arr_empty[1:, :]
idx_move = np.maximum.accumulate(idx_move[::-1])[::-1]
arr[1:][idx_move] = arr[:-1][idx_move]
arr[0, idx_move.any(axis = 0)] = np.nan
```

output:

```
array([[nan, nan, nan],
       [ 1., nan,  7.],
       [ 4.,  2., nan],
       [ 7.,  5.,  9.]])
```

Comment: Beautiful solution thanks: even on this tiny array, it runs in ~18.9 µs while my non-vectorised solution runs in ~185 µs

Comment: Microoptimization: you can replace `~np.isnan(arr)` with `np.isfinite(arr)`.

Comment: It's not necessary to replicate the column indices; `np.arange(arr.shape[1])` is sufficient, due to broadcasting.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser interesting, I think it is worth trying in some cases. These two functioms themselves are also worth comparing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45756854/fastest-way-to-find-non-finite-values

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yeah you are right. I thought there should be better ways to work around this